# jquery custom div to confirm delete action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery to delete a customer comment.

my problem is in "if(confirm" part. I want to show a div asking if user is sure about deleting this comment. not just a browser default alert box.

how can I do this?

```
var Progressajax = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".delete_post").on('click',function(){

                       if(Progressajax) return;
                       Progressajax = true;

var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr("id");

if(confirm('Are you sure?')){

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/js-calls/post_delete.php",
   data: "id="+I,
   success: function(){
            Progressajax = false;
    $(".volta"+I).fadeOut(600, function(){
     $(".volta"+I).remove();
    });
   }
 });
}
return false;
});
});
```

and is there something that I can improve here?
thanks

Comment: You could look at a library like bootstrap with bootbox for nice, simple modals.

Comment: jquery ui has a nice modal option.  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/  You can add your confirmation logic to it.

Comment: See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj64k/15/) for working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to just utilize jquery `.hide()` and `.show()` to hide/show the div element when you need to. You could enhance this to leverage bootstrap as mentioned above to make it more of a visually appealing modal dialog, but this should give you an idea of how the code should work.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Item" id="btnDelete"/>
        <div id="confirmBox">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Yes" id="btnYes"/>
            <input type="button" value="No" id="btnNo" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery_v1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#confirmBox').hide();

    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#confirmBox').show();
    });

    $('#btnYes').on('click', function (e) {
        //Do Delete Action Here
        alert("Item Deleted");
        $('#confirmBox').hide();
    });

    $('#btnNo').on('click', function (e) {
        //Cancel Action Here
        alert("Action Cancelled");
        $('#confirmBox').hide();
    });

});
```